# Monitoring multiple servers connectivity on AWS across accounts

Tags: networking, amazon-web-services

We have around 50 AWS accounts and each account is connect to ON premise , Data centers , some other AWS Accounts.

Sometimes due to misconfig , the connectivity gets lost and then developers tell us later on.

I want o build monitoring solution where i have something running in each subnet in each account which can ping the ips in other account and then publish metric in single AWS account so i can plot it.

Inintially i was thinking of using Lamda and all was ok untill i found that i can't use PING in Lambda and that blow away my solution.

I really dont want to create unnecessary resources. Is there any better way to do it?

Comment: There are many services from many vendors that monitor/graph/report on AWS components, services, etc. Maybe start by looking at Amazon CloudWatch and see if it fits your needs.

Comment: @joeqwerty I am mainly concerned about connectivity from subnet1 to connectivity in subnet 2 in diff aws account .  i want o make sure they are reachable. I am not concered about server ram , disk etc stuff. Idea is if some deletes the peeering or remove routing table entry then those checks should trigger alarms

Comment: Lambda can't ping but can it reach out to a web server on port 80 to check if it's available? I suggest you consider using Transit Gateway, infrastructure as code, and have a very small subset of users allowed permissions to change network resources such as peering, VPN, Direct Connect, etc. This is best done with IAM roles if you have federated users, or groups if you use IAM users.

Comment: @rdg if the *"Idea is if some deletes the peeering or remove routing table entry then those checks should trigger alarms"* then it sounds like some people have permissions outside the scope of their qualifications or expertise.  You can throw money and technology at that, but it seems like the wrong solution.

Answer (score 1):

Please check **AWS Organizations**, https://aws.amazon.com/blogs/security/announcing-aws-organizations-centrally-manage-multiple-aws-accounts/

Other way could be using cloud watch on all account(or centrally) with lambda.

Answer (score 0):

There are two tools which I believe can fit in this scenario but you will have to install their agents on nodes.

- Monit - It can monitor network and trigger based on any malfunction.
- Zabbix - An enterprise level monitoring tool

I have been using both Monit and Zabbix for our servers (both local data center and AWS) in different combination.